# 404 error when I acess the second page of post-type

Tags: php, posts, themes

How can I fix this, I get an error 404 when I access the second page of post-type:

`web.site/clipuri/2012/`

`web.site/clipuri/2012/page/2/`

```
register_post_type('clip', array(   'label' => 'Clip','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,
'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','category', 'post_tag',),
'labels' => array (
'name' => 'Clip',
  'singular_name' => 'Clip',
  'menu_name' => 'Clip',
  'add_new' => 'Add Clip',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Clip',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Clip',
  'new_item' => 'New Clip',
  'view' => 'View Clip',
  'view_item' => 'View Clip',
  'search_items' => 'Search Clipuri',
  'not_found' => 'No Clip Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Clip Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Clip',
),) );

register_taxonomy("clipuri","clip", array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Cat Clip", 'show_ui' => true, 'query_var' => true, "singular_label" => "clipuri", "rewrite" => true, 'with_front' => true));
```

In the theme I use:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'clip')  );
query_posts( $args ); ?>

<div class="nav">
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {wp_paginate();} ?>
</div>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: What template is the theme code from?

Comment: taxonomy-clipuri.php

Comment: Ok, so on your taxonomy archive you need to show 2 different post types?  Let me try to work something up with `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modifying the main query, I think it is best to take advantage of the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action.

When using `pre_get_posts` the `$query` variable is passed "by reference" which means we can directly manipulate the `$query` object with the shortcut functions such as `set_query_var`.  Remove the query code from your taxonomy template, and try the following in your functions.php:

```
function wpa_66609( $query ) {
    if ( is_tax('clipuri') && is_main_query() ) {
        set_query_var( 'post_type', array('post','clip' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_66609' );
```

If that doesn't work, I'll try to debug it.

Comment: Excellent!  I was going to ask you some more questions after visiting your link, but now I don't have to.  Cheers.